# Matlab slows when on different linux desktop

Tags: linux, matlab

I have a long running simulation in matlab that updates figures periodically.  I'd like to be able to continue working in a different linux desktop, but I have discovered that matlab slows to a crawl if I'm not on the desktop it is using.  I assume this is related to it being unhappy about rendering to a non-visible figure, or something.  Has anyone else seen this, or better yet found a solution?  I know I could run without the figures, but I really want to check in occasionally and look at the figures to see status.

Answer (score 0):

I run matlab on a network server with a display. These are some things that I have found make a difference in terms of speed to display graphics, interacting with matlab, etc.

I don't run matlab with a desktop display. So, I use this command to run matlab:

```
/apps/matlab/R2008b/bin/matlab -nosplash -nodesktop
```

Not having a matlab screen to interact with took a bit of getting used to. But, now that I am used to it, I find I can use matlab much faster (i.e. running commands only from the command line). I can still display graphics (a `-nodisplay` call will stop that) and things seem to run pretty quickly.

I would also make sure that you a clearing the figure when you're finished with it. I don't know for certain, but I expect that if you plot over a figure continually, there make be some memory leakage. You said you have a long running simulation. I suspect that close the figure after each time it's plotted may help. Like this:

```
for ii = 1:10
figure(1337);
plot(x,y)
drawnow
close(1337)
end
```

Another option is to run without display (`-nodisplay`), and print the file at each update of the figure.

```
for ii = 1:10
figure(1337);
set(1337,'visible','off')
plot(x,y)
drawnow
print(1337,'-dpng',filename.png);
close(1337)
end
```

And then, use an image editing program to display the output image everytime it's updated.
For example,

```
eog filename.png
```

(You could probably also write a neat little shell script that automatically opens the image, everytime the image is updated.)